# How to share internet over USB from PC to a Windows Phone 8 device?

Tags: 8.0, internet-sharing

I know, that this works out of the box for Zune-compatible devices, but what about Windows Phone 8? I don't have a micro-SIM yet and there is no way to set up a WiFi hotspot.

Comment: Do you mean sharing the phone's connection with the PC, or the PC's connection with the phone?

Comment: `from PC to a Windows Phone 8 device` == PC's connection with the phone

Comment: Rumour has it that when the phone is out of reach of cellular AND wifi, then it may use a connection over USB, but I've not been in a situation to be able to test this myself.

Comment: I have a cyan updated windows phone. And it shows those options mentioned by Zany but still it is unable to access the internet.

Answer (score 5):

By judging what you are trying here to accomplish, I think you are mentioning **Reverse USB Tethering**. Windows Phone 7 had it by default via Zune. In Windows Phone 8 the dev team dropped this feature. So there is no way you can share your PC's internet to phone via USB.

Most likely what you can do to avail internet in phone, you can set an adapter up as an access point or buy a Wifi router. Then connect your phone to the router via cable or Wifi.

Hope the dev team will give us fully functional USB tether support in WP8.1

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no way to share the comptuers data connection with the phone over USB, you could do it with something [Virtual Wifi Wrouter](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/). I've used it and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the developer preview version of windows 8.1 then it is definitely possible !
Press the bing search on your device then type USB instantaneously there will be drop down menu saying USB settings , press on it and then immediately you will be taken to a screen with two check boxes

---

- First one " Ask me before using USB DATA connection "
- Second one " Notify me when i connect to a slower charger "

This is a hidden settings found in the preview version and Im hoping it will be there in cyan update too. 
i haven't tried this out yet but you can have a go and let us know if it works or not

Comment: What Windows Phone version are you using? I can't find the option. I do use the WP8.1 developer preview version.

Comment: they removed it in the official release of 8.1 . it was present in the developer preview. I guess it will be added back again in the 'denim update'

Comment: I *do* have the developer preview *after* the official 8.1 release :P

So, it's the "USB" typed in the bing's "search web or phone" combo box? Does the USB/usb casing matter?

Comment: This doesn't work. No internet will be shared.

Comment: This is a file sharing feature not the internet sharing. See the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to connect to internet over USB. You can only connect to the internet over 2G/3G/4G and Wi-Fi at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 8.1 on Lumia 920 and in search I wrote "usb settings" then went to "local" tab, there it was found. So it is there in 8.1 Cyan version.

Comment: Check your firmware in `Settings > Extras + info` I think Its not available in Cyan but available in Denim.

Answer (score 0):

On my Lumia 830 running WP 8.1 GDR2, I have a *USB menu* inside the Settings that allows to share the data connection from a PC.

[image: Using USB connection on Windows Phone]

Comment: This is a file sharing feature not the internet sharing