# how to connect to my pc internet with my nokia lumia 1020?

Tags: internet

When my nokia lumia 1020 is connected to my PC is it running off my internet or using my data?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you [want your PC to use the Phone's data connetion](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/81/106), whether you [want your phone to use your PC's data connection](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1230/106), or something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I connect my computer to internet through my Windows Phone device?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-can-i-connect-my-computer-to-internet-through-my-windows-phone-device)

Comment: Can we use Bluetooth for net instead of Wi-Fi router?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how you mean "connected" -- if you have it connected via USB, then no. It is still using mobile data. If you are using software like [Virtual Wifi Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) and your phone is connected to ***that SSID*** then WiFi will trump mobile data and it will go out that way.

This used to be a built-in feature of [Windows Phone 7, but as outlined by another answer, its gone from WP8+.](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/5287/1155)