# Automatic sync and slideshow of photos

Tags: 8.1, sync

I have one problem to solve with my Lumia 929 and WP 8.1. I need to every photo I take immediately sync to a PC and join a running slideshow.

Ideally, it should also upload the photo to OneDrive (but it's not required).

There are some informations:

- Mobile and PC is connected via USB
- Mobile is not connected to internet (so upload to OneDrive is impossible)
- PC is connected to internet
- PC is running Windows 7

I need it for one event. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Windows Phone devices use [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) when connected to a PC via USB, they don't show up as true mass storage devices. One of the limitations of MTP appears to be that files added to the device (such as new photos taken) after USB connection was made are not accessible from the PC until the phone is reconnected. As such, it would seem that what you want to achieve is impossible, at least within the parameters you specified.

Seeing as only the phone itself can see the new photos, the only way to do what you want would be to connect the phone to the internet and configure it to auto-upload photos to OneDrive. The PC can the download them automatically. If the location where you're doing the slideshow doesn't have WiFi, you may be able to add a wireless card to the PC and create an ad-hoc WiFi network, then use that to share the PC's internet connection with the phone.

Alternatively, if you're not dead-set on Windows Phone, you might consider Android. Although newer Android devices also connect over MTP by default, [there might be ways to enable standard mass storage mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/22979). Of course, if image quality is paramount, few Android devices will be able to compete with the Lumia Icon, and those that can (e.g. high-end Samsung Galaxy devices) might exceed whatever budget you have for this endeavour.

---

Old answer:

This sounds like something you'll want to do from the PC side. Since the phone is going to show up as a portable device, you can simply use any of [a number of file syncing utilities](https://superuser.com/q/65524/108226) to automatically copy any new photos from the phone to a folder on the PC. Alternatively, you might be able to start your slideshow directly from the phone's Camera Roll folder, assuming of course that the phone is never disconnected.

To automatically upload the photos to OneDrive, simply use the [official OneDrive client](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-gb/download) and point both the file sync utility as well as your slideshow to a subfolder of your choice in C:\Users\username\OneDrive.

Comment: Actually I tried the thing with slideshow from Photos folder, but new photos didn't show until I reconnect the phone.

Comment: What program are you using for the slideshow? The built-in Photo Viewer?

Comment: Yes, built-in Photo Viewer. But better program can't help, because photos didn't show in Explorer before reconnect.

Comment: I tried it, and it looks like you're right - when connected via USB, the PC can only see files that were present during the connection. Any new files added later (such as photos taken) do not show up. Apparently this is a restriction of Windows Phone devices not supporting true mass storage mode, instead using the more limited MTP (Media Transfer Protocol). As such, it appears what you want to achieve may be impossible.

Comment: It would appear that the PC knows the photos are there, though. I took a photo (while connected to my PC), then went into the WP app. It had a placeholder for the picture, but it couldn't display the picture or a preview of it, and it couldn't save it.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the same with the Windows Phone app on Windows 8.1. Also, it took a manual refresh for even the placeholders to show up, so this doesn't seem to be a viable solution.

Comment: I had one last idea - connect phone to internet through USB and PC. But it's not possible. So I must get USB wifi modem. Thanks guys.

//I can't use Android, it should show people how good WP is :)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately reverse tethering (i.e. sharing a PC's internet connection to the phone) [is not possible](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1230/1401). Good luck with your project!