# Reverse Tethering of Lumia 535?

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-535, internet-sharing

I am using lumia 535 and trying to reverse tether it. My phone also has an option to use USB internet.

[image]

When I connect my phone to PC it asks whether to use USB internet or not and when I select to use it says ok but when I try to connect to internet then gives out this message.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or I need to install some software to use USB internet connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**USB tethering is not supported in Windows phone until now.**

The USB data connection you are refering to is not an Internet sharing feature, it is a file sharing feature.

Still thinking data means Internet?

Try this. Don't allow USB data connection and try to access your Memory card. You can't. That is what the prompt and the settings is for.

> When I connect my phone to PC it asks whether to use USB internet or
>   not?

I suppose it asks it as USB data connection and not Internet connection.

For additional details, refer these links:

1. [How to share internet over USB from PC to a Windows Phone 8 device?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/how-to-share-internet-over-usb-from-pc-to-a-windows-phone-8-device)